# Is $a^2b^2-a^2+b^2$ factorable or simplifiable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I'm just wondering if the expression $a^2b^2-a^2+b^2$ is simplifiable or factorable. It just looked like it might have been factorable but I wasn't sure.

Comment: No. Is there a reason why you thought it might be?

Comment: No, it just looked like it might have been factorable but I wasn't sure.  Thanks!

Comment: Should I delete this question now?

Comment: No @CadeLikesToCode You shouldn't delete the question, particularly because it has received an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the following.
$$a^2b^2-a^2+b^2=a^2b^2-a^2+b^2-1+1=1+(b^2-1)(a^2+1).$$

It's not factoring of course.

Comment: It's a nice identity and seems to please the OP, but maybe worth noting explicitly that it's not a factorization.

Comment: I fixed,  Ethan. Is  it good now?

Comment: Yes. Less confusing this way for beginner who come across it.